# Using front end lookup for map display

Tags: craft3, plugin-smartmap

I see the [docs here](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/front-end-address-lookup/) about getting the lat/long of an address from a zip code, city, etc. I am having issues getting the map to render from this info. My code:

```
{% if craft.smartMap.visitor.ip != '' %}
    {% set locations = craft.smartMap.visitor.coords %}
{% else %}
    {% set locations = craft.smartMap.lookupCoords(90210) %}
{% endif %}

{{ craft.smartMap.map(locations, options) }}
```

I get:

> Undefined index: fieldId

How do I convert the lat/long result into one of the [correct location types](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/render-a-map-in-twig/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a minor side note... You'll want to change the first line to this:

```
{% if craft.smartMap.visitor.ip %}
```

It's better to test against a "falsey" IP address, instead of explicitly testing for an empty string. I believe the IP address would resolve to `false` if nothing was found. Either way, a general "falsey" check will work as expected here.

---

It's not currently possible to convert a raw set of coordinates into a more complex object.

That being said, you could fairly easily do it using the built-in `smartMap` JavaScript object...

```
{# Get visitor's coordinates #}
{% if craft.smartMap.visitor.ip %}
    {% set coords = craft.smartMap.visitor.coords %}
    {% set jsCoords = 'smartMap.coords(' ~ coords[0] ~ ', ' ~ coords[1] ~ ')' %}
{% else %}
    {% set coords = craft.smartMap.lookupCoords(90210) %}
    {% set jsCoords = 'smartMap.coords(' ~ coords['lat'] ~ ', ' ~ coords['lng'] ~ ')' %}
{% endif %}

{# Blank map #}
{{ craft.smartMap.map([], options) }}

{# Add visitor marker #}
{% js %}
    smartMap.createMarker('visitor-marker', {
        position: {{ jsCoords }},
        map: smartMap.map['smartmap-mapcanvas-1'],
    });
{% endjs %}
```

---

**UPDATE:** I fixed a bug in v3.0.5 which makes this even easier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can check google map api directly other than using map plugins

Comment: Thank you both. I don't just want to put a pin on a map, I want to display all addresses in a craft structure within a certain distance.